# Using log in detail to fetch records from seperate table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database which people can log into to enter information. What I want is to use the same log in details so that the person can log in and review all the information they have entered into the database.

So basically I have one table with id, studentName , username and password

I then have a separate table called entry which stored the information which they enter with the fields 
id, studentName, textfield1,textfield2, etc ....

So what I want is to write a mysql query which takes the person username from the login page, looks at the related studentName field in the users table and make use of this to fetch all records from the entry table where this name is present.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Matt

Comment: yes it is possible and easily achievable with php session/form post. but what's the question, where are you having problem?

Comment: @kawashita86 I don't know how I would go about writing the query

Comment: I thought his question was pretty clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your entry table, add a reference to your students table via id (preferably id since it's most likely unique if you use auto_increment)

```
entry ( id, studentId, textfield1, textfiel2, ...)
```

Then everytime you need to fetch, do something similar to

`SELECT * FROM entry where studentId = $loggedInUserId`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM entry WHERE studentName = $userName
```

It would probably be better to use the ID field of the student (which I assume is a unique primary key) to do your lookups, as studentName may not be unique. It'll also allow you to skip storing the entire name a second time, which is unnecessary.

Comment: thanks for the reply. You are correct I should not use student name as it may not be unique in the coming years.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and you will need [joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

But why don't you store this data into one table? It looks perfectly valid to store all the student information in one table.

By the way, if you keep your current data model and start using joins, you might want to change the way you match records between those two tables. Matching on a student's name is not a good idea, because it might change or 2 students can have the same name.

It's better to use a (numerical) unique identifier to do the matching, like an ID.

Comment: Thank, I guess my current design is no the best and will have to look to redesign the database at some point. I will read up about joins and see how I get on